# Limiting Network Bandwidth Programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, limit, load-balancing, bandwidth-throttling

I'm developing an application in C# to find Number of users accessing my router (This part is Done)
Now for the no.of users i need to split the total n/w bandwidth among each users locally such that

> UserBandwidth = (OverallAllBandWidth / NumberOfCurrentUsers)

Now I need a methodology to limit bandwidth as per no.of users in C# Win Form

I referred these links
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Bandwidth_throttling.aspx

but all these helps to limit on certain application.

My requirement is such that to apply limitation to NIC itself.

For Eg:

> My N/W B/W is 1MBps currently 2 users are using in the N/W
>
> then my code should limit 500KBps for each users through my App locally.

Comment: Why are you getting the number of users from the router then throttling at your local machine level?

Comment: You are looking for QoS locally I assume: http://ttcshelbyville.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/increase-qos-priority-in-windows-7/

Comment: Question Updated with an example